# No patterns or invalid patterns

Tags: python, django

Here are my files:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^prediction/', include('prediction.urls'))
]
```

**prediction/urls.py**

```
urlPatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list')
]
```

**View.py**

```
def post_list(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello')
```

I'm receving an error saying that prediction/urls.py does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import. I've cross checked multiple sources and documentations. I know this is a basic question, but I just can't seem to spot any syntax or possibly regex mistake that's producing this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `urlPatterns = [`

Looks like your `P` is capitalized when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm gonna have to increase my editor font size to 48.

Answer (score 1):

change urlPatterns in your prediction/urls.py to urlpatterns